# why can't I use import/export code in JSX files visual studio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-2015

I have a React app with dozens of files and I don't use any import / export statements. I have a _references.js file that helps intellisense reference components to each other.

I'm looking for a WYSIWYG component to use in my app but all examples show import statements like this:

```
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
```

When I type this in my JSX file I get:

> JSX illegal import declaration

Do I have to configure Visual Studio (2015) differently in order to use this? What is the deal with this syntax and what are the rules around using it?

I am using [react for .net](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET#licence) so I assume this is what prevents imports from working... but if that is true, then what is the workaround?

Comment: import statements are part of webpack, so I suspect you need to use the webpack options in react for .net. I'm not sure how that is done however.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz I've used webpack for Angular applications in VSCode before but I'm just using the .Net `BabelBundle` and `BundleConfig` stuff to minify and compile my code now and use no imports there.

Comment: I believe babel will look at the import statements as if they are intended for an amd library. Import is very overloaded and is confusing that way. You can still use babel with webpack. And if you do, you should see that import statements work the way that you expect them to again.